# SQL : subquery single or multiple row

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a simple question about SQL.

I have a subquery which returns either one line or more.

I would like in SQL to return the value if there is only one row, or then a string like 'multiple'

I try :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE result.selector END
FROM (
    subquery single or multiple row that contain a col "selector"
) as result
```

Comment: What is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>1 THEN 'Multiple' ELSE max(result.selector) END
FROM (
    subquery single or multiple row that contain a col "selector"
) as result
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `count()` as a window function to your subquery, eg

```
( 
  select <columns>, count(*) over () as rowcount
) as result
```

then you are free to use this in your outer select, eg

```
select case when rowcount=1 then selector else 'Multiple' end
```